# Discord.js - guildMemberUpdate not being called except on Bot user changes

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

With the following code, the guildMemberUpdate event does not call for any user modification at all except for the bot user. What could have caused this change, and how do I troubleshoot this?

VSC with latest npm install of discord.js. Enabled the gateway intents on Discord, too.

```
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // Fire if user has a role
  if (newMember.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "TEST_ROLE")) {
    try {
      // stuff
    } catch(err) {
      // stuff
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Is there an error message when it "crashes"?

Comment: I've tried it just now with no content other than to DM me a test message to confirm it's working. No crash, and when done on other users than the bot, it does nothing. Any way to enable detailed logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you did not enable Guild Members Intent!
To enable, go to:
https://discord.com/developers/applications

Now click on your bot application.

[image: Location of left panel]

Click on "Bot" on the left panel.

Scroll down until you see "Privileged Gateway Intents".

Below that are two toggles.

Toggle "Guild Members Intent" and save.

Hoped this helped you!

Further reading: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway

Comment: As a matter of fact, enabling both presence and guild members intents was able to restore functionality. It's strange that the two are connected. Could you amend your answer to reflect this?

Comment: Privileged Gateway Intents must be toggled in order to view guild members/presences, as these are very sensitive data. You can read more here: https://blog.discord.com/the-future-of-bots-on-discord-4e6e050ab52e