# How to work with member role update part of audit log in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently making a bot to notify people by sending a message when a member role is being updated on the server. I don’t know how to set up the initial part which should be formally client.on part.
Here I have shown a bit of my code that I think should be working but unfortunately it is not working.

```js
const Discord = require(‘discord.js’);
const client = Discord.Client();

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newmember) => {
```

This is what I’m expecting to do:
[image]

Comment: Try adding more to your question. Specifically, your code. I'm rather confused by what you're trying to ask and the one line of code doesn't really help that much.

Comment: I have updated the post which should be showing more information. As well as a screenshot from other bot which I’m expecting to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I give you the code, I'll give you the steps that I took to achieve it.

**Tip:** ALWAYS use the documentation. The `discord.js` documentation helped me a lot of times.

---

### Process:

1. Set up a designated text channel. In my case, I manually grabbed the channel's ID and set it as the variable `txtChannel`. You will have to replace my string of numbers with your own channel ID.
2. I cached every single role ID from the "new" member as well as from the "old" member.
3. Checked whether or not the length of the new member roles array was longer than the old member roles array. This signifies that the member has gained a role.
4. Created a filter function that "cancels" out every single role ID that both new and old role arrays have in common.
5. Grabbed the icon URL - I found out that if you try to get the URL of a user who has the default discord icon, it'll return NULL. To bypass this, you could just grab some sort of invisible PNG online and set it as a placeholder. Else you'll get an error saying that it wasn't able to retrieve the proper URL link.
6. Set up the embed, and sent it into the text channel!

---

### Note:

At first, I couldn't figure out why the bot wasn't registering for other users who have their roles changed. Then I found [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175307/discord-js-guildmemberupdate-not-being-called-except-on-bot-user-changes). The link states that you have to make sure to enable Guild Members Intent. Just follow the instructions from the link and you should be all set! It's a little bit outdated (in terminology), so when it references "Guild Members Intent" it actually is "Server Members Intent" now.

---

### Code:

It's awfully elaborate, but it gets the job done.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let txtChannel = client.channels.cache.get('803359668054786118'); //my own text channel, you may want to specify your own
    let oldRoleIDs = [];
    oldMember.roles.cache.each(role => {
        console.log(role.name, role.id);
        oldRoleIDs.push(role.id);
    });
    let newRoleIDs = [];
    newMember.roles.cache.each(role => {
        console.log(role.name, role.id);
        newRoleIDs.push(role.id);
    });
    //check if the newRoleIDs had one more role, which means it added a new role
    if (newRoleIDs.length > oldRoleIDs.length) {
        function filterOutOld(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < oldRoleIDs.length; i++) {
                if (id === oldRoleIDs[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        let onlyRole = newRoleIDs.filter(filterOutOld);

        let IDNum = onlyRole[0];
        //fetch the link of the icon name
        //NOTE: only works if the user has their own icon, else it'll return null if user has standard discord icon
        let icon = newMember.user.avatarURL();
        
        const newRoleAdded = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Role added')
            .setAuthor(`${newMember.user.tag}`, `${icon}`)
            .setDescription(`<@&${IDNum}>`)
            .setFooter(`ID: ${IDNum}`)
            .setTimestamp()
    
        txtChannel.send(newRoleAdded);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Answer has been accepted and upvoted. And I found that Presence Intent under the cateory Privileged Gateway Intents in Discord Developer Portal need to be turned on in order to use the feature. Anyway thank you for your time. Have a nice day <3

PS Bounty will be awarded once it is available to do so.

Comment: Okay. That's good you found the Presence Intents.