# Is there any way to make the guildMemberUpdate event distinguish between a Role change and nickname change instead of it detecting anyone of those?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Ok so I am trying to make the event guildMembersUpdate try to detect a role change and a nickname change separately which as of now it detects both of them as the same thing, for example when a users role is changed it will just detect it as some sort of change has been made and run a function but the same happens even when the users nickname is changed which is not what i want so how do I make the event distinguish between a role change and a nickname change?

This is the code for reference

```
module.exports = new Event("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember)=>{

let oldRoles = oldMember.roles
let newRoles = newMember.roles
 
 if(oldRoles !== newRoles){
    
    DO ACTION 1  //obvioulsy this is for example

} 

else if(oldMember.nickname !== newMember.nickname) {

   DO ACTION 2 //obvioulsy this is for example

}
```

right now it does not care what is the change and will just do the action 1 even when the actually change was the nick name and if i place the nickname condition first and the role condition after it will just do the nickname condition instead of the role condition

Comment: Remove the `else` from your `else if`.

Comment: @Domi tried it doesnt work

Comment: Provide more information: (1) link to the discord library you use, (2) explain "what" does not work, if you remove the `else`

Comment: Also: probably `rolesA !== rolesB` will not work, since the object itself is the same, however their contents are different.

Comment: Also make sure you enable the `Guild Members` intent - as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175307/discord-js-guildmemberupdate-not-being-called-except-on-bot-user-changes).

Comment: INFO: We need to know what type of data is `oldRoles` and `newRoles`. I suppose they're arrays, and that would mean you can't compare them like `a === b`.

Comment: after removing else the issue is still there and it kind of gets even worse cause both the actions are then conducted simultaneously where as before it was only the action which was above the other. 

can you explain what do you mean by rolesA !== rolesB wont work? would it not detect that the roles are changed? I am a bit to coding in general so sorry if this is a dumb question further more guild members intent is enabled and instead of using just the variables oldRole and newRole what if i used oldMember.roles and newMember.roles directly would it work?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you enable the `Guild Members` intent - as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175307/discord-js-guildmemberupdate-not-being-called-except-on-bot-user-changes).
2. Don't try to check for changed roles using equality comparison (`!==`). Instead you can check changed `roles` as shown in the official api documentation [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-find-all-online-members-of-a-guild):

   ```js
   // Start by declaring a guildMemberUpdate listener
   // This code should be placed outside of any other listener callbacks to prevent listener nesting
   client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
     // If the role(s) are present on the old member object but no longer on the new one (i.e role(s) were removed)
     const removedRoles = oldMember.roles.cache.filter(role => !newMember.roles.cache.has(role.id));
     // If the role(s) are present on the new member object but are not on the old one (i.e role(s) were added)
     const addedRoles = newMember.roles.cache.filter(role => !oldMember.roles.cache.has(role.id));

     if (addedRoles.size > 0 || removedRoles.size > 0) {
       console.log(`roles changed! added roles: ${addedRoles.map(r => r.name)}, removed roles: ${removedRoles.map(r => r.name)}`);
     }

     if(oldMember.nickname !== newMember.nickname) {
       // ...
     }
   });
   ```

### Code Internals

- The relevant `discord.js` code that triggers the event is [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/cfde127072ae06b63f17ba19b3e0d28fddef97d6/src/client/actions/GuildMemberUpdate.js#L30).
- The `GuildMember` class is [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/cfde127072ae06b63f17ba19b3e0d28fddef97d6/src/structures/GuildMember.js).

Comment: `const removedRoles = oldMember.roles.cache.filter(role => !newMember.roles.cache.has(role.id));
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

I got this error

Comment: @Zenxy Which library are you using? and which version?

Comment: discord.js library is 13.0.1

Comment: I can only guess what is happening: is there any chance, that this happens when a new guild member joined the guild etc? In that case, I would assume that `oldMember` might not be populated etc. Maybe you can debug it (learn to use a debugger, it's important!), and find out what values are what exactly. Then come back with screenshot of the results (add them to your initial question), if you cannot interpret them.

Comment: so from what i got from your comment, whenever a newMember is created (i.e a nickname change or a role change for a user) this error occurs. if this not what you wanted can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Zenxy From the code that I see, `oldMember` and `newMember` apparently can never be `undefined`, and their `roles` property neither. Meaning, your error is not explainable, unless you made some other mistake. You might have to paste more code for this to make sense. Also, don't forget to debug it, and see what is what, and why `roles` is `undefined` in the error you reported.